# C# - "random" doubles create reliable collisions on Dictionary inserts

Tags: c#

The snippet below adds random doubles to a dictionary. I was surprised that this failed reliably. witch collision in my dictionary after 20K - 50K inserts (your mileage may vary).

Is this patterns in Random, or the hashing that causes duplicates so quickly?
The code below pretty much never runs through. With a hashing range that is way bigger, I would have never expected that:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var dict = new Dictionary<double, int>();
for (int i = 0; i< 100000; i++)
{
    var nbr = rnd.NextDouble();
    dict.Add(nbr, i); //fails at some point
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the random as key and the index as value and not the other way round?

Comment: It's an artificial test to showcase the problem - I reduced it to this because my string keys (which I generate based on those doubles) caused duplicates.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a GUID, which is made for this purpose?  Does it *have* to be a double value?

Comment: Is this just the birthday paradox?

Comment: The doubles generated by `Random.NextDouble` are actually scaled integers, so the range isn't nearly as big as you'd imagine.

Comment: @Rawling - I thought so too but for a 64-bit space you need to generate ~5 billion values to expect a collision.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, hashing means nothing in your example, because even if keys have equal hashes but are not equal themselves they would be added to dictionary all right. As mentioned above, the range of Random is not that great. If what you're describing comes from some IRL task then you may want to utilize some algorithms like, for example, Box-Muller transform over the output of built-in generator.

Comment: Running it here without the dictionary, just create random doubles and add them to a list and look for matches. i was getting matches way before 100,000. Most cases, I'm seeing 2 matches in 100,000.

Comment: It isn't 64-bit though, random operates on 32-bit space. `NextDouble()` is just `Next() * (1.0 / Int32.MaxValue)`.

Comment: @odyss-jii - That would explain it then, you only need ~70k values to expect a collision in that case.

Comment: [Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,c467f2953a8d2207) is the reference source. Does not look like state of the art. Like observed by @odyss-jii: just 32-bit integer converted to Double.

Comment: @odyss-jii Not sure. When decompiling Next() and NextDouble(), those are different. Next build's on the same Sample() method that NextDouble uses, and then performs int casts.

Comment: @PhilippSumi which `Next`? Parameterless `Next` is completely different from the bounded one. See the source in the link posted by @AxelKemper

Comment: As a sidenote, using a HashSet instead of a dictionary could help with the collisions, you could keep adding until the count is the target size `var rnd = new Random();
var Set = new HashSet<double>();
while(Set.Count < 100000){
 var nbr = rnd.NextDouble();
 Set.Add(nbr);
}`

Comment: @odyss-jii My bad - I was looking at Next(int maxValue). Thanks for the analysis!

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions/ for a graph of probability of collision over number of items in the dictionary. 100000 items with a 32 bit hash has almost a 100% chance of collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). Random uses a 32-bit seed, and you can see from the table that a collision occurs with 50% probability within a 32-bit space after generating around 77k values.

Comment: The *seed* isn't relevant (nor is its size), what's relevant is that it produces no more than 2^31 distinct values to begin with (because it simply scales a 31-bit integer value and presents that result as a double).

Comment: Yeap, the seed length is not relevant, as far as I remember (the seed length could be relevant for the number of different sequences pseudo-algorithm can create). Source: some blurry images from my university courses and common sense.

Comment: Yup, not the seed, but the collision probability is a given I guess. Marked as answered. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting collisions from the use of random.

Running your code but taking out dictionary and just adding the "random" doubles to a list and you will see this rarely finishes without a collision.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var doubles = new List<double>();

    var rnd = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        var nbr = rnd.NextDouble();

        if (!doubles.Contains(nbr))
            doubles.Add(nbr);
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Match");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```