# Get unused value for ID from a set with concurrent services

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, asp.net-core, redis

For the system I'm developing, I have the following requirement:

There is a certain request that a client can make where the backend
needs to allocate an ID with the following restrictions:
(this ID is associated with a 3rd party, so there is nothing we can do to change them)

1. ID is unique
2. Value is limited between values 0 and 2^32 (4294967296)
3. The resource can be deleted by ID. (Reuse deleted Ids)
4. Gaps are allowed (ideally reuse the values in the gaps)

Note that the determination of the ID would be made by one service only (specific microservice let's say) but multiple instances of this service can try to allocate IDs concurrently. If something fails, we can have gaps, but we would like to reuse those values due to the limitation of 2^32

I thought of some approaches (but maybe I'm overthinking this):

***Approach 1:***

1. Have a counter in Redis (or a table on the DB) and increment it.
2. If the process fails, put the ID in a pool (another Redis key or DB table) for reuse
3. When an ID is deleted, the value is added to the IDs pool

***Approach 2:***

1. lock the resource table
2. select the resource table for the existing IDs and determine a new one
3. insert a new resource with the determined ID
4. unlock resource table

***Approach 3:***

1. equivalent to 1, but without a counter, just a pool with all the values from the start
2. server gets an ID from the pool
3. try to create a new resource in the resource table
4. if something fails or a resource is deleted, add ID back to the pool

I'm more inclined to use approach 3, but seems a little complex for what it is. Approach 2 I assume would have non-negligible performance issues.

Am I overthinking this? Is there an easier way to handle this requirement? The project is in ASP.NET C# in case that is pertinent

I thought about Postgres sequences (or equivalent in another DB engine) but from my tests reusing IDs is not trivial, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Another approach was to generate random IDs, but because of the birthday paradox it is not viable for this case I believe (more details here: [C# - "random" doubles create reliable collisions on Dictionary inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545381/c-sharp-random-doubles-create-reliable-collisions-on-dictionary-inserts))

Comment: This is such a common problem, you would get opinionated answers...get some `ideas`  from reading articles like [this](https://medium.com/@sandeep4.verma/system-design-distributed-global-unique-id-generation-d6a440cc8e5)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article. The issue here is that we have these requirements for the ID come from a 3rd party that we need to integrate. If not for their requirement, we would change into some other type of ID.

Comment: It is not clear - you are trying to generate the ID looks like from your approaches, but you are saying "ID comes from a 3rd party service" !?

Comment: We have to generate the IDs on our side, but they will only accept IDs with the given requirements when we make requests to their APIs

Comment: is the requirement that you have to reuse "deleted" ids?  Does that mean for new records?  What is the ID used for?  (Are you coordinating records with the 3rd party's DB?)

Comment: We don't have to reuse them right away, but given the limitation of 2^32 we eventually would need to reuse deleted ones. Yes, the third party keeps state on their side and makes state validation and returns an error if for some reason we try to use an ID that is still in use. I don't want to give too much away on the system itself, but I can say it's related with cryptographic stuff and I believe the requirements are related with the math being it. This is not a simple ID for a shopping bag or wishlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further analysis of the problem, given our required throughput using just database sequences (PostgreSQL in our case) should be enough for a few years, so that's the approach we are taking for now. Some details on how we concluded this below:

NOTE: In the original post I mentioned 2^32, but in reality it is 2^31, so the next sections will take that into account.

I predict we will have around 1 creation per second on this resource. In this case, (2^31) seconds =~ 68.1 years

Even being extremely optimist and assuming 10 creations per second on this resource, it would mean we have (2^31)/10 seconds =~ 6.81 years until we reach the maximum value.

Furthermore, we talked with the 3rd party vendor, and they said that eventually in the future will increase the 2^31 limit, probably to 2^63 which means reaching the limit won't ever be an issue.